# Server rendered control as HTML codebehind not working

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am rendering an ASP.NET server side button into HTML and it works fine except that the code behind function is not working:

```
Button LoadStudents = new Button();
                LoadStudents.ID = "cl" + i.ToString();
                LoadStudents.CssClass = "btn btn-info";
                LoadStudents.Text = "Student List";
                LoadStudents.Attributes.Add("ClassroomID", StringCipher.Base64Encode(o.ClassroomID.ToString()));
                LoadStudents.Click += LoadStudents_Click;
                var LoadStudentsHTML = new BaseHTML().RenderControlToHtml(LoadStudents);

                sb.AppendLine("<tr>");
                sb.AppendLine("<td>");
                sb.AppendLine(o.ClassroomName);
                sb.AppendLine("</td>");
                sb.AppendLine("<td>");
                sb.AppendLine(o.ClassroomDecription);
                sb.AppendLine("</td>");
                sb.AppendLine("<td>");
                sb.AppendLine("");
                sb.AppendLine("</td>");
                sb.AppendLine("<td>");
                //sb.AppendLine("<input type=\"button\" class=\btn btn-info\" value=\"Student list\">");
                sb.AppendLine(LoadStudentsHTML);
                sb.AppendLine("</td>");
                sb.AppendLine("</tr>");
```

Code behind function

```
private void LoadStudents_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Button thisButton = (Button)sender;
            var classroomid = thisButton.Attributes["ClassroomID"].ToString();
        }
```

RenderControlToHTML method

```
        public string RenderControlToHtml(Control ControlToRender)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        StringWriter stWriter = new StringWriter(sb);
        HtmlTextWriter htmlWriter = new HtmlTextWriter(stWriter);
        ControlToRender.RenderControl(htmlWriter);
        return sb.ToString();
    }
```

Any pointers would be most useful.

Comment: `except that the code behind function is not working:` What did you expect it to do? What did it do instead?

Comment: fire the code behind event handler?

Comment: As i understand the control is rendered as plain HTML button and not a ASP.NET button. However if you have the option to add the control to existing runat="server" control. you can do someControl.Controls.Add(thisButton). This works to call codebehind. Edit: onserverclick="LoadStudents_Click" might do the trick aswel